# How to join two videos with cross fade transition using FFMpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I have tried this command but it is not generating expected result

```
finalDuration = video1Duration + video2Duration - transitionDuration

ffmpeg -i video1.mp4 -i video2.mp4 -filter_complex "color=black:1080x720:d={finalDuration}[base];  [0:v]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v0]; [1:v]format=yuva420p,fade=in:st=0:d={transitionDuration}:alpha=1,      setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+((1)/TB)[v1];  [base][v0]overlay[tmp];  [tmp][v1]overlay,format=yuva420p[fv]; [0:a][1:a]acrossfade=d={transitionDuration}[fa]" -map "[fv]" -map "[fa]" output.mp4
```

Note: variable are shown inside `{}`. We need to replace the variables with actual values.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [xfade](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#xfade) and [acrossfade](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#acrossfade) filters. Assuming `input0.mp4` has a duration of 10 seconds, and you want a fade duration of 1 second:

```
ffmpeg -i input0.mp4 -i input1.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v]xfade=transition=fade:duration=1:offset=9[v];[0:a][1:a]acrossfade=duration=1[a]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" output.mp4
```

Also see [FFmpeg Wiki: xfade](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Xfade).